# Logstash: is it possible to save documents in memory?

Tags: logstash, in-memory

I am trying to save data in memory that I would be able to retrieve quickly in my filter part. Indeed, when i receive new documents i want to retrieve former documents related in order to compute some new metrics.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible and if yes how could I achieve that ?

Thank you very much.

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to achieve this would be to use the [`elasticsearch` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html) in order to query an ES cluster for some document or the unofficial [`memcached` filter](https://github.com/coolacid/logstash-filter-cache-memcached), which is probably more up to that task given the features of memcached.

I'm not aware of any official/unofficial `redis` or `hazelcast` filters, though, but that would also be an option since they are both caching technologies.

You should also have a look at the existing [`metrics` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-metrics.html) which might also be of some help depending on your use case, which, by the way, you should detail a bit more if you desire more precise help.

Comment: Thanks val for the all information, this is what i need. I have a question regarding the unofficial plugin memcached. This one seems was released a yead ago. I am currently using logstash 2.3. Do you think that this plugin is working with this logstash version ?

Comment: I'm not certain given [this](https://github.com/coolacid/logstash-filter-cache-memcached/blob/master/logstash-filter-cache-memcached.gemspec#L21): `s.add_runtime_dependency 'logstash-core', '>= 1.4.0', '< 2.0.0'`. Try it out and you'll see. In any case, it might not be too difficult to fork/adapt it. All that might be needed is to increase that version number and recompile the plugin.

Comment: I followed your recommendation but I got a problem. I created a topic on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084705/logstash-plugin-installed-but-not-found ....