# Logstash plugin installed but not found

Tags: rubygems, logstash

I am using logstash 2.3.2 and for one of my project I have to save some data in RAM. I asked a question on stackoverflow ([Logstash: is it possible to save documents in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043846/logstash-is-it-possible-to-save-documents-in-memory/39050391)) to get a filter for that and the most appropriate filter is memcached (even if this one is unofficial).

I downloaded the plugin, I generated the gem file (which is not empty) and I successfully installed the plugin.

[image]

However, when i run logsatsh by using this filter in my configuration file, I get the following error:

```
:reason=>"Couldn't find any filter plugin named 'memcached'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the memcached filter plugin resulted in this error: no such file to load -- logstash/filters/memcached", :level=>:error}
```

Moreover, when i use the command bin/logstah-plugin list,the filter memcached is not present.

I don't understand why it is happening. I followed this discussion (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-plugin-installed-but-not-found/24369) but without success !

So, do you know how I can solve this problem ?

Thank you for your attention and your help.

Joe

Comment: Can you show the full list of commands you've run?

Comment: in my plugin folder: gem build logstash-filter-cache-memcached.gemspec
In my logstash folder: bin/logstash-plugin install /my_path/logstash-filter-cache-memcached-master/logstash-filter-cache-memcached-0.1.1.gem
Then, bin/logstash-plugin list

Comment: Your screenshot above seems cut out, just copy/paste its content into your question above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the process to follow:

A. In `logstash-filter-cache-memcached.gemspec` modify this line

```
s.add_runtime_dependency 'logstash-core', '>= 1.4.0', '< 2.0.0'
```

to

```
s.add_runtime_dependency 'logstash-core', '>= 1.4.0', '< 3.0.0'
```

B. Run the following command to build your plugin

```
> gem build logstash-filter-cache-memcached.gemspec
```

C. In your logstash folder, install the plugin:

```
> bin/logstash-plugin install /path/to/logstash-filter-cache-memcached/logstash-filter-cache-memcached-0.1.1.gem
```

That should yield this:

```
Validating /path/to/logstash-filter-cache-memcached/logstash-filter-cache-memcached-0.1.1.gem
Installing logstash-filter-cache-memcached
Installation successful
```

D. Verify your plugin is correctly installed

```
> bin/logstash-plugin list | grep cache
logstash-filter-cache-memcached
```

E. Run a quick test to see if that works:

```
> bin/logstash -t -e 'input{stdin{}} filter {memcached{namespace => "test" host => "localhost:11211" key => "test" field => "message" ttl=>60}} output {stdout{}}'
```

You should see this:

```
memcached plugin doesn't have a version. This plugin isn't well
 supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. {:level=>:warn}
Configuration OK
```

Comment: thank you Val for your support. But, like yesterday, I am still stuck at the step D where the filter memcached is not found. Previously I did successfully all previous steps. Which version of logstash are you using ? maybe there is something missing..

Comment: I'm using 2.3.2 like you