# Jedis 'front end' for ES

Tags: elasticsearch, redis

I just started learning about Redis. I installed it on my laptop and wrote a simple java client. I have an Elasticsearch instance that handles queries that come in from a web based application. It's pretty fast, but I'm wondering if there is a practical case where I could 'front' the elasticsearch instance with Redis to speed up response time for the clients. In my very limited redis knowledge, I'm wondering if storing the responses from ES queries in Redis would be practical, or would provide any value? More generally, can someone give me an example of how ES and Redis are used together. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One use case for having Redis in the picture is to use it as [temporary buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043846/logstash-is-it-possible-to-save-documents-in-memory/39050391#39050391) when loading documents into Elasticsearch via Logstash.

Since Redis is basically a cache, its main purpose is to make data available fast that would not be promptly available otherwise, because the back-end service you're querying is not fast enough. Since you are saying that your Elasticsearch instance is "pretty fast" (whatever that means), why would you want to cache the response?

Also, when you put a cache into the picture, you have other new concerns that arise, most importantly, how do you expire the cache, when and at which frequency? So if your data in Elasticsearch is pretty stable, you might benefit from a cache. However, if your data in Elasticsearch is changing frequently, you'll often be faced with many issues of stale data in your Redis cache, and that's a problem you don't want to have.

In my opinion, it's much better to spend time improving your ES queries and mappings to deliver blazing fast data, than to spend your time tuning a cache that might be useful 1% of the time.

Comment: thanks, this makes sense. My thinking was a simple cache implementation in redis, storing the search string as the key, and the response as the value. So, from the front end, if someone performed a search, it would hit redis first to see if the same query was run previously, if so, return the previous result, if not, hit ES. I just wasn't sure how practical that was.

Comment: Yes, but if your data changes, the response to a previous search might have changed and the cached one might not be accurate anymore. That's the whole issue with caches, i.e. to know whether and when the cached data is stale and wipe it clean.